# Alignment of images from a Fancybox gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, image-gallery

I have this fancybox gallery [gallery 1](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/msb/das-msb-team.html) & [gallery 2](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/msb/ausstattung.html)

The images of these galleries dont float to the left like they should.

This is my CSS:

```
.gal { display:block; padding:3px; border:1px solid #ccc; float:left; margin:4px;     margin-top:20px; overflow:hidden;}
.gal img { display:block; float:left; }
.gal:hover {background:#ccc;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gal-a" >
<a href="gal/5.png" class="gal" rel="gal"><img src="gal/thumb/5.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="gal/6.png" class="gal" rel="gal"><img src="gal/thumb/6.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="gal/7.png" class="gal" rel="gal"><img src="gal/thumb/7.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="gal/8.png" class="gal" rel="gal"><img src="gal/thumb/8.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

And how can we have different gallery groups of different image sizes?
Sometimes I need the original look of the image in thumnail and sometimes just a section clipping of the image.

I looked on the net but dont found something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the images have different heights, the floats are "snagging". That is, as an anchor/image tries to float to the left, it catches on a tall image in the row above.

A better way to do this would be to use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`:

```
.gal {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 20px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

(You could try `vertical-align: bottom` instead of `top`, as you might prefer the look. Up to you. Worth playing with.)

Answer (score 1):

They are not being positioned as desired because the images are of different heights.

You can solve this by adding a height to the `.gal`.

```
.gal { height:132px /*based on the smallest height for thumbnails*/; display:block; padding:3px; border:1px solid #ccc; float:left; margin:4px;     margin-top:20px; overflow:hidden;}
```

You can choose what height you desire based on your preferences.

As for the thumbnail clipping/cropping, there is no means to automatically generate thumbnails exactly as desired for what you are describing. You will have to do it manually.